# Bring Word to Front

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want a Word application to come to front, see code below:

```
string caption = wordApp.Caption;
IntPtr handler = FindWindow(null, caption);
SetForegroundWindow(handler);
wordApp.Visible = true;
```

The errors I got are:

```
Error CS0103: The name 'FindWindow' does not exist in the current context  
Error CS0103: The name 'SetForegroundWindow' does not exist in the current context
```

I guess I miss a reference even though the compiler does not say so. Am I right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371836/findwindow-does-not-exist-in-current-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C#, use Process.GetProcessesByName(), something like this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
SetForegroundWindow(processes[0].Handle);
```

In order to use SetForegroundWindow(), you have to have this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be of good help to your problem: [FindWindow MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The library that contains it is under User32.lib

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your functions before using them, I'm assuming you want to call the Windows APIs: FindWindow and SetForeGroundWindow.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

You can find more examples in MSDN documentation.

Comment: Well, Word has activated but was not brought to front