# How do I restore a minimized(hided) wpf app to foreground

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I have a wpf application on .net 4.8. If i close the app i use MainWindow.Hide() to bring it in Systemtray and to minimize the app. But if a user starts a new instance of the app it should be bring to foreground the minimized app. For this I use this pice of code:

```
var currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            var runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == currentProcess.ProcessName && p.Id != currentProcess.Id);

            if (runningProcesses != null)
            {
                var window = runningProcesses.MainWindowHandle;

                ShowWindowAsync(window, 1); //SW_SHOWNORMAL
                SetForegroundWindow(window);

                this.Close();
            }
```

If the app is only minimized it works perfekt. If it is hided (Systemtray) the MainWindowHandle is always 0.
I have noticed that if I hide the app it goes from apps section to the background process section in the taskmanager. Is there a way to avoid this action or is there a way to bring it in foreground?
Thanks

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21156860/4489263

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) api to find MainWindow handle. then you can bring it to foreground.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);
```

```
var mainWindowHandle = FindWindow("","MainWindow"); //Suppose your window name is MainWindow
ShowWindowAsync(mainWindowHandle , 1); //SW_SHOWNORMAL
SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle );
```

Comment: This doens't work for minimized apps in systemtray. The answer in the post comment works fine for that case

Comment: try using the pid.